# haskell -- How to avoid this infinite type? (Associated data and StateT)

Tags: haskell, typeclass, infinite, typing, associated-types

I want to set the type of the state parameter, of a state monad tranformer, to an associated type of that monad transformer. However, this results in constructing an infinite type,

```
s = AssocTyp (StateT s m) a
```

The intuition as to why this isn't really a problem is that,

```
AssocTyp (StateT s m) a = AssocTyp (StateT s' m) a
```

for all `s` and `s'`. However, the compiler isn't smart enough to figure this out. I've read that in some cases, a newtype can be used to avoid infinite types; how do I do it?

Here's minimized code to reproduce the question,

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State

class MyMonad (m :: * -> *) where
    data AssocTyp m :: * -> *

instance MyMonad m => MyMonad (StateT s m) where
    data AssocTyp (StateT s m) a = StateTA (AssocTyp m a)

isAssocTyp :: Monad m => (AssocTyp m a) -> m ()
isAssocTyp x = return ()

x = do
    v <- get
    isAssocTyp (v)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. However, the equality you state,

```
AssocTyp (StateT s m) a = AssocTyp (StateT s' m) a
```

is not true, because you are using a *data* family rather than a *type* family. The following code compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures, TypeFamilies #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State

class MyMonad (m :: * -> *) where
    type AssocTyp m :: * -> *

instance MyMonad m => MyMonad (StateT s m) where
    type AssocTyp (StateT s m) = AssocTyp m

isAssocTyp :: Monad m => (AssocTyp m a) -> m ()
isAssocTyp x = return ()

x :: Monad m => StateT (AssocTyp m a) m ()
x = do
    v <- get
    isAssocTyp v
```

The difference between type families and data families is that [data families are injective](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Type_families#Injectivity.2C_type_inference.2C_and_ambiguity), which means the following implication holds if `DF` is data family:

```
DF a b c = DF a' b' c'   =====>     a = a',   b = b',   c = c'
```

This is not what you want in your case.

Comment: ah, thanks very much!! I think I'm confusing equality on the type level and data level.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case a data family is what you want, I have a variant that does type check:

```
isAssocType' :: (Monad m1, Monad m0) => (AssocTyp m1 a) -> m0 ()
isAssocType' _ = return ()
```

Comment: Sorry, the `isAssocType` was reduced (for the sake of example).